# Why does Python throw a KeyError when accessing an unset property?

Tags: python, exception, keyerror

What are the rationale and implications for throwing `KeyError` instead of returning `None` when accessing an unset property on a Python dictionary?

I know that language design involves trade-offs, some of them based on practical concerns and some based primarily on philosophy. From a computer science perspective, why has Python been designed in this way?

#### A couple of notes to frame the question

- I'm primarily curious to know if this was a practical decision (i.e., it gives the developer more options to recover from the error than just returning `None`), or if the choice was philosophical (i.e., "accessing an unset property is, in Guido's opinion, an exceptional case").
- Python's `dict.get` function has this functionality, but the literal notation appears to be optimizing for the case where the program considers an unset value exceptional.
- It's worth noting that exception handling is considered by some to be hard to reason about because it involves [a control flow that is distinct from the main program](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~weimer/p/weimer-toplas2008.pdf)
- If Python returned `None` instead of raising an exception, a program could still check for the key's existence prior to accessing its value if it did want to treat unset and `None` values differently. But since we wouldn't have access to the exception programming flow, I'm interested to learn what we might lose?

Comment: A value can be set to `None` in a dictionary. Returning KeyError clearly indicates that the key does not exist in the dictionary and not that it exists and points to a `None` value.

Comment: What happens if the key's value *needs* to be `None`, because there the key isn't needed but there is no present value. What would the advantages be? Have you thought of that? A `KeyError` is raised because the key does not exist. You can always *catch* the `KeyError` as well...

Comment: @TeneCursum, that's a good point. However, you can also check whether a dict has a certain key before accessing it, which gives you the same information. I'm wondering why Python has been optimized for this case rather than the other possible case, and what practical ramifications that has?

Comment: Put too many attempts at papering over errors with "sane" default behavior into your language spec instead of forcing explicitness and you get PHP.

Comment: By the way, if you want a Python dictionary that returns None rather than raising KeyError, you can do that -- use a DefaultDict.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But that's not built-in: it's an additional import.

Comment: Its much like a `list` `IndexError` - its essentially an overflow condition. One wouldn't expect a bad list index to return a `None` and neither should the syntactically identical `dict` access.  It has the added advantage of raising the exception at the point of error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes from [Python design philosophy](http://python-history.blogspot.ru/2009/01/pythons-design-philosophy.html):

> - Errors should not be fatal. That is, user code should be able to recover from error conditions as long as the virtual machine is still functional.
> - At the same time, errors should not pass silently (These last two items naturally led to the decision to use exceptions throughout the implementation.)

And there is a classic case, where language that do not prefer to yell are broke: `None` is not always means missing key (which means broken message), it may also mean optional, but unset key (which is OK). Take for example **JSON**:

```
>>> j = json.loads('{ "key": null }')
>>> j['key']
>>> j['nokey']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'nokey'
```

With `None`-by-default this example becames more clunky. Take, PHP, for example:

> `json_decode` returns null for invalid input, even though null is also a perfectly valid object for JSON to decode to—this function is completely unreliable unless you also call `json_last_error` every time you use it.

From [PHP: a fractal of bad design](http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it does seem like the Python philosophy you pointed out is the root cause of the design choice. I'd still be interested to delve into more reasoning on the ramifications of this choice (many other languages don't use exception control flow in this case and haven't turned into PHP), but maybe I'll save that for another question.

Comment: I would like to actually add that Javascript does not have this problem of PHP even though it does not throw error, because accessing a non-existing key of a dictionary in Javascript will return `undefined` instead of `null`.

Comment: @WongJiaHau, neither question nor my answer implies anything about JavaScript. If you want to expand my answer it may be worth mentioning other languages, i.e. C++, Perl -- they have different approaches to this case.

Answer (score 1):

A `dict` can store *any* value (including `None`) so the only way (when using the `[]` syntax) to distinguish between a missing key and a key that maps to whatever you think
would be a good sentinel is to raise an exception.

```
>>> d = {'foo': None}
>>> print d['foo']
None
>>> print d['bar']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'bar'
```

For cases where you don't care about the distinction, you can use the `get` method instead, which deliberately returns `None` (or a sentinel of your choosing) for non-existent keys.

```
>>> print d.get('bar')
None
>>> print d.get('bar', 7)
7
```

Comment: Not sure I agree.  You could just have `NON_EXISTENT_KEY = object()` as a sentinel, and that's (probably) never going to show up in your dictionary...  And if it does, just use `in`.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's review our terminology:

> ...when accessing an unset property on a Python dictionary

You are not accessing a property.  You are retrieving a key.  That's why it's called a `KeyError`.  Properties are a special case of attributes, which is why they raise `AttributeError` instead

As for the why, you have type theory to thank.  I have a dictionary `d` with (say) strings as keys and integers as values.  For *any* `k`, this rule really ought to hold:

```python
assert isinstance(d[k], int)
```

If you return `None`, then the rule fails in that case.  Raising an exception is the normal way of indicating that you can't satisfy an operation's postcondition.  In this case, the assertion doesn't have a chance to fire, because the exception is raised while the expression is still being evaluated.

Comment: The "why" is a bit weak. The reasoning only applies to dictionaries with only a single type of value, which is not enforced anywhere in Python.

Comment: @chepner I disagree. Any dictionary that stores data might want a key, to store an option, even if there is no value for it.

Comment: @chepner: It is certainly the most common use-case, however.  See [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#generics) for example.  While you can specify union types, doing so is significantly more cumbersome in most cases.

Comment: PEP 484 is a *long* way from defining the semantics of `dicts` in general. (It's also technically not yet accepted as part of Python, and the type hints provided will only be used by static analyzers, not the run-time.)

Comment: @Zizouz212 That's my point. `None` as the returned value for a non-existant key can't be distinguished from an existing key that maps to `None`. If that's not a concern, the `get` method can be used.

Comment: Replying to the original response: This is exactly the type of response I'm looking for. And I can see why this would be the case in Haskell, which consistently applies type theory to make all kinds of safety guarantees. I think pointing to type theory is really valuable. However, Python allows me to set a dict value to `None` if I want to make the assertion you listed fail. Is type theory applied consistently across Python's language features?

Comment: @PeterManning: Well, lists raise `IndexError` instead of producing `None`...  `str` and `bytes` in 3.x are pretty insistent about being two different types.  You *can* do just about anything you like, but in practice, it's more useful to comply with basic type theory, and Python tries to make this easy for you.

Comment: @chepner: Go check the authorship on that PEP.  If it doesn't get accepted, it'll be a matter of "is the implementation done yet?" rather than "do we like this?"

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't be accepted; I said it wasn't *yet* accepted. And a document describing type hints for function arguments still has nothing to do with `dict` semantics.

Comment: @chepner: I'd say it reflects Guido's vision of how the language is "meant" to be used.  Which includes mostly homogenous containers.  `Tuple[]` allows for mixed types.  `Mapping[]` isn't designed for it.